# How to safely extend credentials to other contributors to my S3-hosted OS project

Tags: amazon-s3, open-source

I have an open source project with several contributors. The project's home page is hosted on Amazon S3. At the moment, the S3 bucket is on my personal account. Only I have access to it, and I pay the hosting (~$5 a month). There are other personal buckets on my account that contributors should not have access to.

I'd like to allow other contributors to modify the site. I'd also like to enable e.g. TravisCI to deploy to the site, which requires extending some credentials to third parties.

1. Is it necessary to set up a separate Amazon account entirely, or is IAM sufficient for my needs?
2. If IAM is the way to go, should there be a single IAM user shared among all contributors, or should I create a separate one for each contributor?
3. Do I need MFA? If so, how to safely distribute TOTP keys?
4. Any provisions I should make for succession (i.e. bus factor)?
5. Anything else I should know?

Thanks for any ideas or experiences here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it necessary to set up a separate Amazon account entirely, or is IAM sufficient for my needs?

You should probably have an account for this project that is separate from any accounts you use for purposes unrelated to this project, for clean separation and in case you want to hand over control.  What isn't in the account doesn't need to be protected from users who shouldn't see it.

Cross-account privileges are possible, so if others already have accounts, it's possible for you to authorize their existing credentials without knowing their secrets, but it's more complex.

> If IAM is the way to go, should there be a single IAM user shared among all contributors, or should I create a separate one for each contributor?

You should absolutely create one for each contributor.  That's kind of a no-brainer.  [Accountability.](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudtrail/)

> Do I need MFA? If so, how to safely distribute TOTP keys?

It depends on your need for the added security.  MFA is great and it's also a hassle.  But you don't have to (and shouldn't) distribute the MFA secrets for virtual MFA.  The user can log in with his/her credentials and create and download that themselves [if you allow it](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_delegate-permissions_examples.html#creds-policies-mfa-console).

> Any provisions I should make for succession (i.e. bus factor)?

Heh, [bus factor](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bus_factor).  Yes, you probably need a trusted adjutant with a high privilege level.  In my accounts we don't actually use the root credentials, ever, but typically two people have a physical copy of the root credentials, though we do sometimes ride together in the same elevator, and we really shouldn't do that.

> Anything else I should know?

Read the documentation.  It takes a bit of time to sink in, but it takes less time if you get your hands dirty and play with it.  Be sure when granting privileges that you verify that things which should not work do indeed not work, not just verify that things which should work indeed do work.  But that applies to any authentication and authorization implementation.

Use IAM instance roles in EC2.  <strike>Even if you can't think of a reason why an instance needs a role, give it one with no permissions anyway, because an instance can only be given a role at launch... yet</strike> Formerly, you could only add an IAM role to an instance at launch, but [AWS announced on 2017-02-09](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/new-attach-an-aws-iam-role-to-an-existing-amazon-ec2-instance-by-using-the-aws-cli/) that you can now attach an IAM role to an instance after launch.  As always, you can change the permissions granted to a role at any time.

Read about user groups.  Attach users to groups and policies to groups to simplify granting the same privileges to multiple users.

Unrelated: activate billing alerts for your account to notify you when costs exceed thresholds you select.